# Intellij not opening Reactor marbles

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, reactor

I am running intellij 2020.3.3 Ultimate ( on windows ) and I have a project in which I am using project-reactor.
Reactor javadocs are enhanced with marbles under the correct directory ( /doc-files ... ) but when I download the javadoc jar file intellij refuses to open the images [image: Image not rendering]

This is the configuration of intellij pointing at the javadoc jar.
[image: javdoc config]

If I unzip the jar file I can see the images inside and if I change the javadoc path from the jar to the unzipped file it will actually load the images.

Obviously unzipping each jar maven downloads is not an option.

Any suggestions how can this problem be resolved?

Comment: There's [open issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256643) for this problem. However, the images should display in a dedicated [documentation panel](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/documentation-tool-window.html).

Comment: oh I did not stumble on this issue while I as searching. Thank you